# How to upload multiple files in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to find a solution to add multiple files using a drag and drop form.
I'm using Django's Rest API and React.

This is what i have been trying so far but it seems like this will only do for one file at a time:

```
class FileCollection(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    Files = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded', null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mpg', 'mpg2', 'mpeg'])])
```

How can i make it so i can upload multiple files at once with the rest api? I only found some answers on here regarding images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only show the model in your question, I assume you are asking about how to create a model that stores multiple files. Your current `Files` field is actually only a single file since you declare it as a `FileField`. To have multiple files, you need to use multiple `FileField`s:

```
class FileCollection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded', null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mpg', 'mpg2', 'mpeg'])])
    file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded', null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mpg', 'mpg2', 'mpeg'])])
```

Now this will have 2 files. If you want an arbitrary number of files, you first need to have a model that stores one file and use a `ForeignKey` to add that file to a collection:

```
class FileCollection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded', null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mpg', 'mpg2', 'mpeg'])])
    collection = models.ForeignKey(FileCollection)
```

If you want to add a file to multiple collections, you can use `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey`.

This only addresses the model since that is all you posted in your question. You will also need to create a view for this. Note that REST API doesn't really allow for file uploads. You will likely need to use a multipart form instead of a REST API.

Side note: fields should start with lower case in python. For example, use `name` instead of `Name`.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I found out that there is also a multipart parser for DRF.